# Unsure if I'm using setState correctly because my state is not updated during initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a state that stores the current app's theme either dark or light. I use useEffect hook to store the state changes in localStorage so that when the user refreshes the page, their preferred theme will get saved and another useEffect hook to update my state during the initial load. However, my state does not update during that initial load.

Things I've tried:

1. Make sure the useEffect during initial load is placed **before** the useEffect to store the theme state
2. Use Promise to make sure that my changeTheme function is only triggered after the state has changed on load
3. I logged my results so I know that localStorage did not have any problems with saving my states or keeping track the changes, but the setState function inside my first useEffect hook was the one that did not update my state properly.

Below are my codes:

```
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(themeStorage))
    if (loadedTheme) {
      console.log("Initial load")
      console.log(loadedTheme);
      console.log("Setting theme to localStorage")
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => { setTheme({ dark: loadedTheme.dark }) })
        .then(() => { console.log(theme) })
        .then(() => changeTheme())
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(themeStorage, JSON.stringify(theme))
    console.log("Inside useEffect to save changed theme")
    console.log(theme)
  }, [theme])

  function changeTheme() {
    console.log("Inside changeTheme function");
    console.log(theme);
    if (!theme || !theme.dark) { //light turns to dark
      for (let vars of Object.keys(varTheme)) {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${vars}`, varTheme[vars][0]);
      }
      setTheme({ ...theme, dark: true })
    }
    else {
      for (let vars of Object.keys(varTheme)) { //dark turns to light
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${vars}`, varTheme[vars][1]);
      }
      setTheme({ ...theme, dark: false })
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you have a prop with the theme passed initially can you set it like `const [theme, setTheme] = useState({theme: props.theme});` outside of the useEffect, when the component is first loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you *think* the issue is, but I suspect that you are seeing/describing `theme` not updating in the first `useEffect` hook.

## Issue

The reason for this is that React state is considered const and immutable. Within the `useEffect` callback the `theme` state value is closed over in callback scope and no matter of waiting or Promise chaining will change the state value closed over in scope.

```
const [theme, setTheme] = useState({}); // <-- initial state

useEffect(() => {
  const loadedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(themeStorage))
  if (loadedTheme) {
    console.log("Initial load")
    console.log(loadedTheme);
    console.log("Setting theme to localStorage")
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => { setTheme({ dark: loadedTheme.dark }) })
      .then(() => { console.log(theme) }) // <-- still initial state
      .then(() => changeTheme())
  }
}, []); // <-- mounting "instance" of state
```

You then invoke `changeTheme` which from the enclosure and it will also sill access the "stale" state of the enclosure.

## Solution

LocalStorage is synchronous, so you can set your initial state from it with an initializer function.

```
const loadThemeFromStorage = () => {
  const { dark } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(themeStorage)) ?? {};
  return { dark };
};

const [theme, setTheme] = useState(loadThemeFromStorage());
```

Now with the state already initially set you can safely call `changeTheme` in the mounting `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Initial load");
  console.log(theme);
  changeTheme();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(themeStorage, JSON.stringify(theme));
  console.log("Inside useEffect to save changed theme");
  console.log(theme);
}, [theme]);
```